# Can Coded UI tests and MTM be used to create a test suite that will automatically play all test cases?

Tags: tfs, coded-ui-tests, mtm

When creating a test suite in selenium ide it is possible to let all test cases in a test suite run in a continuous manner and see results when finished. I'm looking into creating test suites in Microsoft test manager and possibly automating with the code with cuit, my question is, is it possible to run the tests one after another with no manual interaction, as from what I've seen so far, it seems you have to manually verify the test results in each step for MTM tests and manually verify the pass or fail status at the end of the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a test case and tie an automated test case (Selenium/CUIT) to it in Visual Studio. This flips a flag in the test case work item to "automated", and allows you to automatically execute those test cases on test agents.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx